# How can I insert a string value to an html table?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to insert a value directly to html table. Is it possible?
Im trying this in Django. Just a basic try.

This is the code of my views file :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from scripts.stock import run


def index(request): 
  now=run() 
  html = '''<head>
   <title>Stock Forecasting</title>
   </head>
   <body style="background-color:lightgrey;">

   <h1 style="color:blue;text-align:center;">Stock Forecasting</h1>
   <p>(Paragraph)</p>
   <style>
     table, th, td {
       border: 1px solid black;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       }
      th, td {
       padding: 5px;
       }
      th {
       text-align: left;
       }
   </style>
   <table style="width:20%">
   <caption><b>Stock Data</b></caption>  
   <tr>
   <th>Company</th>
   <th>Price</th>
   <th>Open</th>
   <th>Previous close</th>   
   <th>Low</th> 

   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Yahoo</td>
   <td>%s</td>
   <td>%s</td>
   <td>%s</td>
   <td>%s</td>
   </tr>

  </tr>
</table> 

<br><br>

</body>

'''


return HttpResponse(html)
```

This is my script code :

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
from pprint import pprint
import threading 
def run():
    yahoo = Share('YHOO')
    file = open("scripts/newfile.csv", "w")
    file.write("High,Open,Prv Close,Low\n")
    a= yahoo.get_days_high()
    b= yahoo.get_open()
    c= yahoo.get_prev_close()
    d= yahoo.get_days_low()
    file.write(a+",")
    file.write(b+",")
    file.write(c+",")
    file.write(d+",")
    return (a,b,c,d)
    threading.Timer(5.0, run).start()
```

what i want is to insert the values that is returned from the script in html table..

Comment: You script doesn't return anything, so there's nothing to render.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be looking for [Django Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the indexes of the data where you have %s:

```
{{ now[0] }} #  a

{{ now[1] }} #  b

{{ now[2] }} #  c

{{ now[3] }} #  d
```

Also better to have your html in a template and iterate through like:

```
{% for x in now %}

    <td>{{ x }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with Django. Using `%s` is simple [Python 2 string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). So

```
html = '''<head>
   <title>Stock Forecasting</title>
   ...
   </body>''' % now
```

would replace the placeholders with the values returned by `run()`.